# Как сделать str_replace?

Tags: php, replace

Здравствуйте
Есть ссылки вида:

```
http://xxqwz.com/uploads/posts/2015-12/1419005960_unnamed.png
http://xxqwz.com/uploads/posts/2015-09/1419005960_unnamed.png
http://xxqwz.com/uploads/posts/2014-10/1419005960_unnamed.png
http://xxqwz.com/uploads/posts/2012-11/1419005960_unnamed.png
```

и т.д
Как мне сделать так, чтобы осталось только название файла. 
То есть `1419005960_unnamed.png`

Comment: Разделите по слэшу строку на массив. Возьмите последний элемент массива.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo basename("http://xxqwz.com/uploads/posts/2015-12/1419005960_unnamed.png");
```

Вывод: `1419005960_unnamed.png`

Кстати, разница в выполнении между моим ответом и принятым составляет практически 10 раз в пользу моего ответа. Так-то!

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь: `$name = substr(strrpos($url, '\\') + 1);` Найти последнее вхождение символа \ и взять часть строки после него.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте заменить с использование `regex`

Выражение `(.*)\/(.*)` даст вам 2 группы, где 2я группа то что вам нужно.

Вот тут ваш пример https://regex101.com/r/uH3tD9/1

Comment: Извините, а для чего вы первую пару скобок поставили?

Comment: первые скобки помогают отрезать не нужную часть, что бы дойти до последнего \

Comment: Ну вообще если их убрать, то ничего не изменится. Это, в принципе, все равно, но зачем плодить карманы, которые не нужны